How to Filter Links Using <LinksControlOptions> with Link Comment Value in Azure DevOps Process XML?
I'm customizing a work item type in Azure DevOps using the process XML and need to filter links based on the comment value associated with them. Specifically, I want to control the visibility or applicability of links in the work item form based on the content of the link comments.
I understand that the  element in the process XML allows filtering links based on LinkType and WorkItem Type, but I couldn't find any documentation or examples that show how to filter links based on the comment value.
Is it possible to filter links using the  element with the link comment value in Azure DevOps process XML? If so, could someone provide an example or guide on how to implement this?
Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!


Is it possible to filter links using the element with the link comment value in Azure DevOps process XML?

I am afraid that there is no such method can use LinksControlOptions(XML Process) to control the visibility or applicability of links in the work item based on the link comment.
Refer to this doc: LinksControlOptions XML elements
Here is the LinksControlOptions definition:
<LinksControlOptions ViewMode="Static | Dynamic" ZeroDataExperience="Development" ShowCallToAction="true | false"   WorkItemTypeFiltersScope="project | all" >
   <ListViewOptions GroupLinks="true | false" />
   <LinkFilters>    
      <ExternalLinkFilter Type="ExternalLinkName" />
      <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="WorkItemLinkName" />
   </LinkFilters>
   <WorkItemTypeFilters>
      <Filter WorkItemType="WorkItemTypeName" />
   </WorkItemTypeFilters>
   <Columns>
      <Column RefName="FieldReferenceName"/>
   </Columns>
</LinksControlOptions>

Currently, we can only Hardcode the link types(work item type, work item link or external links) in the LinksControlOptions.
It doesn't support automatically controlling the links based on the link comment.
